# How to measure coverage of a non-test run of python

Tags: python, code-coverage

I have a custom-built integration test suite in python, which is technically just a run of `python my_script.py --config=config.json`. I want to compare using different configs in terms of what fraction of lines of code in my project will be activated.

Specific content of my_script.py is not relevant - it is a launch point that parses config, then imports and calls functions defined in multiple files from ./src folder.

I know tools to measure coverage in pytest, e.g. coverage.py; however is there a way to measure coverage of a non-test python run?

Comment: I have never seen a tool to measure coverage outside of a test. Why do you even need this?

Comment: @YodogawaMikio for analytics about our codebase.

Comment: As @Yodogawa said, never seen coverage if it is not for test. A similar idea that I have used for other languages are tools to find dead code. Maybe that gets you in the right direction. [just to start of with](https://github.com/jendrikseipp/vulture)

Comment: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/  looks like it does what you ask, not in a test environment or anything. pytest-cov is for coverage inside test runs, but coverage.py has routes to run on any script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coverage.py doesn't care whether you are running tests or not.  You can use it to run any Python program.  Just replace `python` with `python -m coverage run`

Since your usual command line is:

```
python my_script.py --config=config.json
```

try this:

```
python -m coverage run my_script.py --config=config.json
```

Then report on the data with `coverage report -m` or `coverage html`